How do I get my Homing Missile to Destroy Enemy Targets
I have everything working when it comes to tracking the enemy the only thing I can't seem to get working is the homing missile destroying the enemies.
The catch though I want the homing missile to last for a certain amount of time destroying multiple enemies and then destroying itself after time expires.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HomingMissle : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float _speed = 5f;

    [SerializeField]
    public float _rotateSpeed = 200f;

    private Transform _target;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Enemy _enemy = transform.GetComponent<Enemy>();

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        _target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy").transform;

        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * _speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * _speed * Time.deltaTime); 

        if(transform.position.y > 8)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (_target == null)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.up * _speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            Vector2 direction = ((Vector2)_target.position - rb.position);

            direction.Normalize();

            float rotateAmount = Vector3.Cross(direction, transform.up).z;

            rb.angularVelocity = -rotateAmount * _rotateSpeed;

            rb.velocity = transform.up * _speed;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Hit" + other.transform.name);

        if (other.tag == "enemy")
        {
            Debug.Log("homing hit enemy"); 
        }
    }
}

Here is my enemy script
[SerializeField]
private float _enemySpeed = 1f;

private float _kamikazeSpeed = 6f;

private Player _player;

// handle to animator component 

private Animator _animate;

private AudioSource _explosionSX;


private float _fireRate = 1.0f;
private float _canFire = -1f;

private float _enemyFrequency = 1.0f;
private float _enemyAmplitude = 5.0f;
private float _enemycycleSpeed = 1.0f;
private float _enemyAggressive = 3.0f;

[SerializeField]
float _rayCastRad = 8.5f;
[SerializeField]
float _rayDistance = 8.0f;

private Vector3 _enemyPos;
private Vector3 _enemyAxis;

[SerializeField]
private GameObject _enemyLaser;

[SerializeField]
private GameObject _shieldVisualizer;

private bool _isenemyshieldActive = false;
private int _randomshieldedEnemies;
[SerializeField]
private SpriteRenderer _shieldRenderer;
private int _shieldStrengh = 1;

private bool _isLaserDetected;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    _player = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Player>();
    _explosionSX = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    _enemyPos = transform.position;
    _enemyAxis = transform.right;
    _randomshieldedEnemies = Random.Range(0, 7);
    _enemyAggressive = Random.Range(0, 5);


    //null check player
    if (_player == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("The Player is NULL.");
    }

    //assign the component

    _animate = GetComponent<Animator>();

    if (_animate == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("The aninator is NULL");
    }

    _randomshieldedEnemies = Random.Range(0, 5);

    if (_randomshieldedEnemies == 3)
    {
        ActiveShield();
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //move down at 4 meters per second

    //if bottom of screen
    //respawn at to with a new random x position

    CalculateMovement();

    if (Time.time > _canFire)
    {
        _fireRate = Random.Range(1f, 3f);
        _canFire = Time.time + _fireRate;
        GameObject enemyFire = Instantiate(_enemyLaser, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Laser[] lasers = enemyFire.GetComponentsInChildren<Laser>();
    }
}


void CalculateMovement()
{

    transform.Translate(Vector3.down * _enemySpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    _enemySpeed = Random.Range(3f, 5f);

    if (transform.position.y < -5f)
    {
        float randomX = Random.Range(-15f, 15f);

        transform.position = new Vector3(randomX, 15, 0);
    }

    if (transform.position.x < 1)
    {

        _enemyPos += Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * _enemycycleSpeed;
        float randomX = Random.Range(-15f, 15f);
        transform.position = _enemyPos + _enemyAxis * Mathf.Sin(Time.time * _enemyFrequency) * _enemyAmplitude;
        _enemycycleSpeed = Random.Range(1f, 5.0f);
    }

    if (_player != null)
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, _player.transform.position) < _enemyAggressive)
        {
            KamikazePlayer();
        }
    }
}

public void ActiveShield()
{
    _isenemyshieldActive = true;
    _shieldVisualizer.SetActive(true);

}



private void KamikazePlayer()
{
    if (transform.position.x < _player.transform.position.x)
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * _kamikazeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else if (transform.position.x > _player.transform.position.x)
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.left * _kamikazeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else if (transform.position.y > _player.transform.position.y)
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.down * _kamikazeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    // if other is Player 
    //Destroy Us
    //damage the player

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {

        //damage player
        Player player = other.transform.GetComponent<Player>();

        if (player != null)
        {
            player.Damage();
        }

        _animate.SetTrigger("OnEnemyDeath");
        _enemySpeed = 0;
        _explosionSX.Play();
        Destroy(this.gameObject, 2.8f);
        
    }

    //if other is laser
    //laser
    //destroy us

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Laser"))
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        
        if(_isenemyshieldActive)
        {
            _isenemyshieldActive = false;
            _shieldVisualizer.SetActive(false);
            return;
        }

        if (_player != null)
        {
            _player.AddScore(10);

        }

        _animate.SetTrigger("OnEnemyDeath");
        Destroy(this.gameObject, 2.8f);
    }
}

}

Please use the correct language tag. This doesn't seem to be a C++ related question.

well you know how to destroy something, as you do it in the script.. you know what the other object is because its provided.. so... have you put the 2 together?

Your requirements sound quite straight forward
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    Debug.Log("Hit" + other.transform.name);

    if (!other.CompareTag("enemy")) return;
    
    Debug.Log("homing hit enemy");
    Destroy(other.gameObject); // destroys enemies as long as the missile is alive and continues flying
}

you currently have no timer for the self destruct but even that's simple. You already have a condition for the y position - simply add another
private float liveTime = 5f; // set to whatever your lifetime should be

void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.up * _speed * Time.deltaTime); 

    liveTime -= Time.deltaTime;

    if(transform.position.y > 8 || liveTime <= 0f)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

or if you rather only wanted to start the timer after hitting the first enemy than you can directly use the optional delay parameter of Destroy(Object, float)
private bool firstHit;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    Debug.Log("Hit" + other.transform.name);

    if (!other.CompareTag("enemy")) return;
    
    Debug.Log("homing hit enemy");
    Destroy(other.gameObject); // destroys enemies as long as the missile is alive and continues flying

    if(firstHit) return;
    
    firstHit = true;
    Destroy(gameObject, 5f); // Destroy yourself after 5 seconds -> adjust the delay time
}


In general though when dealing with physics and Rigidbodies you shouldn't move your missile through Transform at all as it might break collision detection.
Also further you mix moving the missile in Update as well as FixedUpdate which seems very odd.
Rather use
rb.MovePosition(rigibody.position + ((Vector2)transform.up) * _speed * Time.deltaTime);

only in FixedUpdate and remove the transform.Translate from Update and Start

wait are you saying only change the line in FixedUpdate and delete the whole line in Update and Start?

_target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy").transform;

The above code uses "Enemy" with a capital E
    if (other.tag == "enemy")
    {
        Debug.Log("homing hit enemy"); 
    }

And the collision detection part has the string with a lower case, am guessing the correct one is the first one as I think you would get a "UnityException: Tag: Enemy is not defined."
In general this is a good lesson in not using hard coded strings and declaring them as a const variable or something
Furthermore consider using/creating an Enemy class as suggested by user - bleat interteiment
I would personally expand it even further by having a structure like this (although it might be currently beyond the scope of what you're doing)
public class DamageObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Amount;
}

public class HomingMissle : DamageObject
{
    //your code
}

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    int Health = 10;

    public void HitBy(DamageObject dmg)
    {
        Health -= dmg.Amount;

        if (Health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}


The best practice in any object oriented language is to think on the object scale. Don't use CompareTag(), you should instead use TryGetComponent() method.
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    Debug.Log("Hit" + other.transform.name);

    if (other.TryGetComponent(out Enemy enemy))
    {
        enemy.Die(); // or Destroy(enemy.gameObject);
    }
}

This would require your enemy gameobject to have Enemy component attached to it. With this, you can delegate your enemy functionality to the enemy itself instead of your HomingMissle class. You can have all sorts of enemy types and all of them would inherit from your base Enemy class.
Also, your FixedUpdate and Update methods, both doing missile movement. I don't know the specifics of your project, so I don't think I can help you with that. All I can do is provide you with some tips.

You shoudn't do the same operation (e.g. missile movement) inside both Update and FixedUpdate.
You are currently altering movement of your missile using two different methods: rb.velocity = X and transform.Translate(Y). You should stick to one.
If you want your missile to destroy itself after some time, you should use time as a parameter and not transform.position


As someone who is also part of the GameDevHQ course whence this problem came, if you want to remain consistent with how the lasers were implemented, your enemies will check for contact in its OnTriggerEnter2D function and apply damage there. As others have noted, you can handle the destruction after a period of time either by polling the time in Update, or setting up a Coroutine on Start or Awake.
So your enemy contact code will look something like this (may vary depending on what else you're doing in your code):
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Laser"))
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);

        Damage();
    } else if (other.CompareTag("Missile"))
    {
        // No destroy here since we want the missile to keep going
        // Note that if you have a shielded enemy, this might result
        // in destruction in two frames as the missile plows through first
        // the shield then the enemy unless you implement "mercy invincility"

        Damage();
    } else if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        other.transform.GetComponent<PlayerScript>()?.Damage();

        Die();
    }
}


bool countDown = false;
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{  
    if (other.tag == "enemy"  )
    {
        destroy(other.gameObject)
        if(!countDown)
        {
            StartCoroutine(waitThenDestroy(10, this.gameObject)); // 10 seconds 
        }
    }
}

Private IEnumerator waitThenDestroy(int time, gameObject obj)
{ 
    countDown = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    Destroy(obj);        
}


Or you could simplfy that and just use the delay on the destroy method.
